# График символьной функции в MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Как строится график символьной функции в MATLAB?

Answer (score 1):

```
syms x; y=sin(x); x=0:0.001:3; plot(x,eval(y));
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте fplot

```
syms x
fplot(sin(x), [xmin xmax])
```